# Nginx redirect request to index file with angular deployement

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-location

I have deployed an angular app on a nginx server ( unbuntu 20 on digital ocean), now to be able to directly access the url like [www.example.com/test](http://www.example.com/test) or to reload the page. I have modified the configuration file to add try_files like under the image but it doesn't work

`http {

```
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    server {
            location / {
                    listen 80;
                    listen 443 ssl;
                    server_name pisqre.com;
                    root /var/www/html;
                    index index.html index.html;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
    }
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

}`

I tried several configuration like adding 404 at the end of try_files, removing (listen, server_name, root) ...but none of these methods work.

when i reload or try to directly go to subdirectory like mywebsite.com/test i have a not found page like that.
[image: not found page]

Folder structure
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide information about the error or the expected behavior that's not happening?

Comment: Can you share the folder structure?

Comment: @RobertoYoc when i reload or try to directly go to subdirectory like mywebsite.com/test i have a not found page

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: After some search the problem was ssl so i have modified the nginx conf file like that. And now everything is okay
[image: nginx conf file]